# How can we use EF Fluent API with reflected types

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

How can I use fluent API with few reflections for stop repetition?

sample code;

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class SemiStructuredEntity : Entity
{
    public virtual int DocumentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentId")]
    public virtual Document Document { get; set; }
}

public class Payment : SemiStructuredEntity
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Member : SemiStructuredEntity
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Document : Entity
{
    public string UniversalId { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

and fluent;

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.Document)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(u => u.DocumentId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Document)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.DocumentId);
```

When we need another one class inherited by SemiStructuredEntity base class we must define another fluent for it.

My dream is; (my question commented lines in code block)

```
    List<Type> targetTypes = getSemiStructuredEntities();
    ///
    ///and now  How? How can i define fluent for all of targetTypes in second statements?
    ///
```

or

```
List<Type> targetTypes = getSemiStructuredEntities();
foreach (Type item in targetTypes)
{
           ///
           ///And now How? How can i define fluent for this type
           ///
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to use reflection? You can define your mapping [in reusable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594718/entity-framework-4-1-rc-code-first-entitytypeconfiguration-inheritance-issue/5614982#5614982) by using types derived from `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` and registering these types into `modelBuilder.Configurations` in your `OnModelCreation` method.